# connect to SQL Anywhere by TCP/IP

Tags: php, apache, sqlanywhere

I'm new in sql anywhere, currently I'm trying to connect using PHP.

This is what I've got so far:

```
$conn = sqlanywhere_connect ( "UID=usr;PWD=pass;ENG=serv;DBN=bd_name;COMMLINKS=TCPIP{HOST=10.1.1.189:2638}" );
```

SQL Anywhere is installed on another machine, where I can't run apache, website is running on localhost (xampp). This is only for test, when website would be ready I will connect to correct db.

This is error I've got:

```
Warning: sqlanywhere_connect(): The SQLAnywhere client libraries could not be loaded. Please ensure that dbcapi.dll can be found in your PATH environment variable. in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\cache\includes\elements\modsnippet\25.include.cache.php on line 21
```

I haven't got `dbcapi.dll` file, but I'm not sure I should have it.
In [documentation](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1001/en/dbpgen10/pg-php-connect.html) I couldnt find this file (SQL Anywhere 10 which I've got), but for SQL Anywhere 11 I could find pages where was info about this file.

To use `sqlanywhere_connect` I've download SQL Anywhere module for curren ver. of PHP onto my machine and I've add it to `php.ini` file.

What should I do? Should I download missing file? Would it be enough or I could get more errors asking for other files?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and the solution proposed here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sql-anywhere-web-development/zK9Tf-X3cYk/GAoqK2DnB9EJ
worked for me.

Specifically, my xampp + php needed the 32 bit dbcapi.dll but when I installed SQL Anywhere 12 I neglected to check the box to install the 32 bit version as well.  Re-installing, chossing "modify" and installing the 32 bit SQL Anywhere 12 got "php test.php" working.

Answer (score 0):

I would down load the missing file and go from there you are using xamp which is pre-built to talk to mySQl I doubt there is any extra .dll in the Instillation to connect with SQLAnywhere